Standard flexible/multi-signer/boolean-logic customizable signature scheme?
Is there a standard flexible signature scheme that, for example, might represent the required conditions for validity (whether all signers or a subset or specific conditions) in Boolean logic followed by a collection of acquired signatures from the listed public keys in various formats?
The purpose would be to verify someone’s id such that the hash of all the prerequisites and public keys is the user’s identity and the boolean logic can be tested against the provided signatures and sub-signatures for its validity.
Is there a standard format or convention for this or will I have to roll my own?
X509 isn’t flexible enough for arbitrary Boolean logic and relies heavily on central authorities, so my use case would modify x509 so much it’s not really x509 anymore.

A concrete example might help. It's not clear whether you're asking for an advanced cryptography functionality (like ring signatures) or just a file format?
